# User does not exist issue

Tags: php, pdo

I am trying to find out what is wrong with my following code. What it does is it checks in my database if a user exists and if it exists it then checks if its banned and then it checks if the input of the password is correct. Anyways I've got a small issue where I have an account in my database under the table 'users' and with the username 'admin' but when I try and login as it, it shows up: The user admin does not exist

```
$check = $dbh->prepare("SELECT * FROM users WHERE username = '$username'"); 
var_dump($check);
$check_array = $check->fetch();

if ($check_array == 0){
    var_dump($check_array);
    $error.= 'The user <strong>'.$username.'</strong> does not exist.<br>';
}else{
    $r = ($check_array);
    if ( $r["banned"] == '1') {
        $error.= 'You are currently banned, you can not log in.<br>';
    }else{
        $r = ($check_array);
        if( $r["password"] !== $password){
            $error.= 'The password you entered is incorrect.<br>';
        }else{
```

This is coded in PHP, PDO

Comment: From where does this `$r["banned"]` comes from

Comment: What is the result of `var_dump`?

Comment: @Mr.Alien $r["banned"] comes from $r = ($check_array); which was meant to be above $r["banned"], I've just fixed this

Comment: @Lion the var_dump below the query = `object(PDOStatement)#3 (1) { ["queryString"]=> string(44) "SELECT * FROM users WHERE username = 'admin'" }` and below `if ($check_array == 0){` its  bool(false)

Comment: I believe the crucial issue here is that you've never executed the SQL statement, you've simply prepared it. The fetch is then going to fail and 0 is truthy to false, which is what the `fetch()` returned. Please add `$check->execute();` before your first `var_dump($check);` and let us know.

Comment: @Ohgodwhy Thankyou! This made it check it perfectly.

Answer (score 2):

I believe the crucial issue here is that you've never executed the SQL statement, you've simply prepared it. The fetch is then going to fail and 0 is truthy to false, which is what the fetch() returned. Please add $check->execute(); before your first var_dump($check); and let us know.

Also of importance:

Please note that you should not directly pass in variables to the prepare statement and should instead use the `bind_param` method

```
$check = $dbh->prepare("SELECT * FROM users WHERE username = ?"); 
$check->bind_param(1, $username, PDO::PARAM_STR);
$check->execute();
```

This is a more secure method of sanitizing your user input and should shore up vulnerabilities.

Comment: Thanks, works perfectly. I can now login, just need to fix a few things up with other parts of coding and it should be all working.